# Reload an image once on my page through jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

On my page, for some reason, one of the image is only showing after I reload the page. When the page first loads, it only shows the partial image.

I don't quite know the reason why it's happening.

I am trying though to reload only the image when the page loads, but only once. I can't figure out how to do it.

Here is what I tried:

```
    <img src="images/myimage.png" border="0" usemap="#Map3" >
    <map name="Map3">
      <area shape="rect" coords="145,274,472,426" href="#slide-2-8">
      <area shape="rect" coords="283,28,641,240" href="#slide-2-4">
      <area shape="rect" coords="26,31,258,229" href="#slide-2-2">
    </map>
```

Comment: try loading image in pagebeforeshow event

Comment: the only problem is that `images/myimage.png` isn't showing, am I right?

Comment: yah, only image doesn't show. I actually can't refresh. It happens on the first run but when the page loads it shows fine.

Comment: @Steve , give ur Website URL to test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check the jquery-imageloader ??

http://beatak.github.io/jquery-imageloader/